# Find files with matching substrings and move them into directory

Tags: bash, files, directory

My directory contains a list of `.idat` file pairs ending with either `_Grn` or `_Red`.

For each pair, I want to create a directory named after the substring before the first `_` delimiter and move the files into their respective directories.

If the directories don't exist, create them before moving the files.

My code:

```
for file in *.idat; 
do directory_name=${file%_*} \ 
mkdir directory_name \ 
if ${file%_*}==directory_name; 
then 
mv $file directory_name;
fi; 
done
```

Traceback:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Filenames:

```
00f3408c-5ad1-4afb-9eac-3392aa92e42c_noid_Grn.idat 
00f3408c-5ad1-4afb-9eac-3392aa92e42c_noid_Red.idat 

0317b249-9256-47fe-9533-3ca91c07e3fd_noid_Grn.idat 
0317b249-9256-47fe-9533-3ca91c07e3fd_noid_Red.idat

039f8688-b4cd-4931-a8f5-40bcb1fbd8f0_noid_Grn.idat  
039f8688-b4cd-4931-a8f5-40bcb1fbd8f0_noid_Red.idat
```

Expected folder names:

```
00f3408c-5ad1-4afb-9eac-3392aa92e42c
0317b249-9256-47fe-9533-3ca91c07e3fd
039f8688-b4cd-4931-a8f5-40bcb1fbd8f0
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob # dotglob
for file in [^_]*_@(Grn|Red).idat; do
  dirname=${file%%_*}
  mkdir -p -- "$dirname" &&
    mv -- "$file" "$dirname"
done
```

(uncomment the `dotglob` if you also want to consider hidden ones).

`\` at the end of the line is a *line continuation*. It's use to break long lines to improve legibility.

```
do directory_name=${file%_*} \ 
mkdir directory_name \ 
if ${file%_*}==directory_name
```

is the same as

```
do directory_name=${file%_*} mkdir directory_name if ${file%_*}==directory_name
```

So it would ask `mkdir` to create directories called `directory_name`, `if`, `00f3408c-5ad1-4afb-9eac-3392aa92e42c_noid==directory_name` with `directory_name=00f3408c-5ad1-4afb-9eac-3392aa92e42c_noid` passed in its environment.

Then the shell complains about that `then` without a corresponding `if`.

To do pattern matching in `bash`, you use the `case` construct or the `[[ text = pattern ]]` operator, but you don't need to here.

Also remember that expansions in list contexts must be quoted in bash, and the non-option arguments must be separated from options with `--` for most commands.

`${var%pattern}` removes the *shortest* string that matches the pattern from the end of `$var`. You need `${var%%pattern}` that removes the longest string for it to remove all from the first `_`. You'll notice that we use `[^_]*...`  as the glob pattern to make sure the files don't start with a `_` which would result in an empty directory name.

If you know there's always a `Grn` file for each `Red` file, you can reduce the number of invocations of `mkdir` and `mv` by half by doing:

```
shopt -s nullglob # dotglob
for file in [^_]*_Red.idat; do
  dirname=${file%%_*}
  mkdir -p -- "$dirname" &&
    mv -- "$file" "${file%_*}_Grn.idat" "$dirname"
done
```